# Flutter & Firebase : How do I get a specific field from a specific document into a stream?

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream

I have been trying to get a specific field from a specific document into a stream. But I always got null. How do I fix this?

Function

```
Stream<List<String>> getError() {
    DocumentReference errorReference =
        appSettingCollection.document('report_error');

    final Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = errorReference.snapshots();

    return snapshots.map((doc) {
      //print(doc.data['types']);
      return doc.data['types'];
    });
  }
```

Main

```
return StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: User_DatabaseService().getError(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          
          final List<String> errorTypes = snapshot.data;
          print('In Error Report : $errorTypes'); // I got null??? But why?
///--------
```

}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have taken wrong stream.
Try to correct Stream

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('CollectionName')
          .document("DocumentID")
          .get(),
```

And use it below for accessing specific field as:

```
document["FieldName"]
```

For accessing single field you will need to access whole document.I will suggest to use FutureBuilder follow the link below and you will get your answer more precise.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Comment: cloud_firestore have breaking changes on 0.14.0, deprecating many of the methods but the idea should be similar